How to Invoke Base Class Implementation from a Mock Method in Google Mock?
I'm currently working on unit tests for a C++ project using Google Test and Google Mock. I've encountered a scenario where I want to mock a class method but under certain conditions, call the original (base class) implementation of this method from the mock.
For the sake of explanation, let's say we have an interface IMyInterface with a method performAction, a concrete class MyConcreteClass implementing this interface, and a mock class MyMockClass derived from MyConcreteClass:
class IMyInterface {
public:
    virtual ~IMyInterface() = default;
    virtual void performAction(int param) = 0;
};

class MyConcreteClass : public IMyInterface {
public:
    void performAction(int param) override {
        // Actual implementation
    }
};

class MyMockClass : public IMyInterface {
public:
    MOCK_METHOD(void, performAction, (int param), (override));
};

In my tests, I want to set up an expectation on MyMockClass such that when performAction is called, it should actually execute MyConcreteClass's performAction method. I've tried to use Invoke in Google Mock like this:
TEST(MyTest, TestPerformAction) {
    MyMockClass mockObj;

    EXPECT_CALL(mockObj, performAction(_))
        .WillOnce([&mockObj](int param) {
            return mockObj.MyConcreteClass::performAction(param);
        });

    mockObj.performAction(42);
}

However, I'm unsure if this is the correct or recommended way to achieve such behavior, especially considering best practices and avoiding potential pitfalls with object slicing, incorrect polymorphic behavior, etc.
